# Save parent and child with NOT NULL constraint in one call

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities with bidirectional relationship like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    // some other attributes and methods
```

```java
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    // some other attributes and methods
```

In a controller I have this `POST` endpoint:

```java
    @PostMapping("/parents")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Parent create(@RequestBody Parent parent) {
        return this.service.save(parent);
    }
```

and service:

```java
    @Override
    public Parent save(Parent parent) {
        return this.repository.save(parent);
    }
```

The repository that the service calls is just a simple interface extendind Spring `JpaRepository<Parent, Long>`.

If I call this endpoint to save new parent and child in one shot with this JSON in a request body

```json
{
    "name": "exampleParent",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "exampleChild"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get an error: `PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value`

I could find two "workarounds" that fix this issue:

1. The same action with cascading saving of children works fine if I remove `NOT NULL` constraint, thus `optional = false` and `nullable = false`.
2. Change save() method in Parent service to first save Parent, then set parent to all children and save them like this:

```java
    @Override
    public Parent save(Parent parent) {
        Parent newParent =
                this.repository
                        .save(new Parent(
                                parent.getName()
                        );

        List<Child> children = parent.getChildren();

        children.forEach(child -> {
            child.setParent(newParent);
            this.childRepository.save(child);
        });

        newParent.setChildren(children);
        return newParent;
    }
```

Question: Is there some cleaner way to save Parent and Child entities in one shot with maintaining the NOT NULL constraint (and not using that ugly code in second workaround)?

Comment: This is somewhat strange,  I can run the case with eclipse-link instead of hibernate.  No errors there.

Comment: Did you try the different version of spring-boot and hibernate?